# Reverting the keybindings that I don't specify in the init files without restarting emacs?

Tags: key-bindings

When I have test-assigned some function on mouse-3, and I want to revert the default feature assigned to it to compare which function is more useful to assign to the mouse-3, I have to comment out the particular assigning statement from the init file, **and then restart emacs**. I could do (global-unset-key  (kbd "")), but that would just unable the mouse-3 instead of get back the default feature assigned to it. It's cumbersome to restart emacs every time I'm in this kind of situation (I've been in this kind of situation many times.); is there a way to do this without restarting?

Answer (score 2):

Load library `mouse.el` (again). It binds the default mouse keys.

Or just visit it (`M-x find-library RET mouse.el RET`) and evaluate the relevant key-binding code.